# (Non) differentiability of a function in a point.

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm studying the solution of the following boundary value problem:

$ u''=\lvert\sin x\rvert \lvert\cos u\rvert$

$ u(0)=0, u(2015)=7$

(which - unless I have done it wrong - I showed to exist). Clearly the solution is of class $C^2$.

Now, I would like to determine if it is more regular. I suppose it is not because

$f(t.s):= \lvert\sin(t)\rvert\lvert\cos(s)\rvert$ it is not differentiable at $0$.

But how can I prove it?

Thank you :)

EDIT: I replaced $u(1)=1$ with $u(2015)=7$

Comment: Click on edit to see how I typed $\sin x,$ then edit the remainder accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If you can show $u([0,1])= [0,\pi/2-\epsilon]$ for some $\epsilon>0,$ then we actually have

$$u''(x) = \sin x\cdot \cos (u(x)), \,\, x\in [0,1].$$

Comment: Thanks very much. I understood how to conclude that $u$ is actually $C^{\infty}$ thanks your comment. However I just realized that I made a mistake in modifying the original problem by replacing $u(2015)=7$ with $u(1)=1$, thinking naively that the approach would have been the same. Can I modify the original question? Because I actually don't understand how to make use of your hint in this latter case.